# Auto Mirror add-on error 2.8a

Tags: add-on

I couldn't find any fix anywhere for this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\addons\mesh_auto_mirror.py", line 167, in execute
    threshold= bpy.context.scene.AutoMirror_threshold) 
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.81\2.81\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 201, in __call__
    ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Zero normal given


location: <unknown location>:-1
```

Any ideas how i can fix this?

edit: i was trying to mirror on the x-axis(positive side), then this error popped up

so i tried again in object mode and it works fine. i don't what's wrong with edit mode.

and sorry for my english

Comment: Please describe what exactly you're trying to do and under which circumstances this error occurs.

Comment: Try object unselected or delete object and try create again